# Psshutdown works via cmd line but not via app

Tags: windows

I am using winpower to hibernate 2 computers in the event of power failure.
I use the command.

```
"C:\Program Files\PSTools\psshutdown.exe" -h -t 1 \\COMPUTER -u xxx -p yyy
(with the quotes)
```

When I use it directly via command line this works fine, but when I use it inside the app it does not work, I suspect a permission issue of some sort.

Can anybody think what the issue might be.

Comment: Do you have anything against using the command line version? If not, you always have the option of writing a batch file to do this automatically. That could be even more convenient than the UI. :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the command  line version.    
I am using a batch file to do it, the batch file does hibernate the remote PC, but not when run by the app.

Comment: Oh, well I'm sorry then I must have misunderstood your question. I'm afraid I don't have any specific ideas to why it wouldn't be working in the application, but I agree that it sounds either like a permissions error, or perhaps there's an unnoticed field that went unattended, or a field that was left unfilled, and maybe that is the source of your problem. I'm not sure.